# What does 'arms pattern' refer to in Rust? The book's explanation isn't clear. Can you provide a concise clarification?

Tags: rust

In the Rust book it's written

> A match expression is made up of arms. An arm consists of a pattern to match against, and the code that should be run if the value given to match fits that arm’s pattern. Rust takes the value given to match and looks through each arm’s pattern in turn.

But the example is very weak (is not the goal of the book)

I am not a native English speaker, maybe is that why this simple phrase is so confusing to me. Even chatgpt didn't give me an answer about that.

What is the Arms Pattern?

Comment: There is no "_arms pattern_", there are arms, and each arm contains a _pattern_ and an _expression_. The _pattern_ is the part that's before the `=>` and it describes the condition that the arm should match, and the _expression_ is the part that's after the `=>` and it describes the action that should be taken when the pattern matches.

Comment: "Each arm's" is the [possessive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive) of "each arm" here, so "each arm's pattern" means the same as "the pattern for each arm". You can replace the term arm with branch, if you find that less confusing.

Comment: The Rust book is [translated in several languages](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-06-translation.html).

Answer (score 2):

A match “arm” is simply one of the cases of the match. The arm consists of a pattern to match against, followed by =>, followed by the value to produce if the pattern matches.

“Arm’s pattern” here simply means the pattern for that particular arm. For example, in the match expression

```rust
let x = 1;

match x {
    1 => println!("one"),
    2 => println!("two"),
    3 => println!("three"),
    _ => println!("anything"),
}
```

there are four arms, with patterns 1, 2, 3 and _ (match anything) respectively.

Comment: The pattern is a *pattern* and not just a "value" because it can match more complex stuff than just static values.  If `x` was a `Result<String, Error>` you could use `Ok(value)` as the pattern, which puts the String in `value` locally for the code block of the arm.

Answer (score 1):

The "arms pattern" is the pattern (plain english word) that belongs to the arm (each case for the match statement is called an arm, as is common for branching statements).  It is not a pattern as in the "design patterns" buzzword.

The thing that should match to select a specific arm is called a pattern (rather than, say, a value) as it is not limited to static values, but can, thanks to the expressivenes of the rust type system, describe parts of the value while selecting other parts for use in the pattern.

Here's an example where the thing to match is a tuple:

```rust
match (price_in_cents / 100, price_in_cents % 100) {
   (d, 0) => format!("{d} dollar"),
   (0, c) => format!("{c} cents"),
   (d, c) => format!("{d}:{c}"),
}
```

Note that order is important here, if I would have put the last arm first it would match any value (and the compiler would warn that the other arms are unreachable).

Note that `_` in the example from @nneonneo s example is not a magic symbol to match anything, it is a declaration of a variable to put any value in.  The only thing special is that the name `_` implies that you are not going to use it.  You can say `x` with the same result, except that the compiler will warn about you declaring a variable `x` and then not using it.